# In blender's voronoi.c file, what is the variable float co[2]?

Tags: c, blender

Here are the main structures that are defined in the voronoi.c (https://github.com/martijnberger/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/voronoi.c) file and some of its importing libraries:

```
//from BLI_voronoi.h
typedef struct VoronoiSite {
    float co[2];
    float color[3];
} VoronoiSite;

typedef struct VoronoiEdge {
    struct VoronoiEdge *next, *prev;

    float start[2], end[2]; /* start and end points */

    /* this fields are used during diagram computation only */

    float direction[2];     /* directional vector, from "start", points to "end", normal of |left, right| */

    float left[2];          /* point on Voronoi place on the left side of edge */
    float right[2];         /* point on Voronoi place on the right side of edge */

    float f, g;             /* directional coeffitients satisfying equation y = f * x + g (edge lies on this line) */

    /* some edges consist of two parts, so we add the pointer to another part to connect them at the end of an algorithm */
    struct VoronoiEdge *neighbour;
} VoronoiEdge;

typedef struct VoronoiTriangulationPoint {
    float co[2];
    float color[3];
    int power;
} VoronoiTriangulationPoint;
```

Code file: https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/branches/ge_components/source/blender/blenlib/BLI_voronoi.h

VoronoiSite contains a color, which I'm assuming is the color for each cell, as both the references to VoronoiSite contain a loop from i = 0 to the integer "sitestotal" and a variable called co, maybe a 2d coordinate?

What is diagram computation?
VoronoiEdge is fairly self explanatory, it references the edges of a voronoi cell, but why are the coordinates in 2D when the node in blender can go up to 4D? I will continue to look through the voronoi.c script for an answer to that.

VoronoiTriangulationPoint has that co variable again, int "power" likely refers to the power k of the distance function a^k + b^k = c^k which blender makes adjustable in the voronoi node.

**In conclusion for BLI_voronoi.h, what is float co[2]?**

The other struct I'm wracking my head about is VoronoiEvent from voronoi.c. I dont really need the answer for this one but it would be great if somebody knew the answer.

```
//from voronoi.c
typedef struct VoronoiEvent {
    struct VoronoiEvent *next, *prev;

    int type;       /* type of event (site or circle) */
    float site[2];  /* site for which event was generated */

    struct VoronoiParabola *parabola;   /* parabola for which event was generated */
} VoronoiEvent;
```

"Site" or "circle" is a little cryptic, I'm sure its referring to the shape of the voronoi cell but referring to the shape of a cell with a series of VoronoiEdge edges as "site" or "circle" doesn't make any sense.
"Parabola for which event was generated" is completely beyond any hypothesis of mine.

Comment: TLDR read http://blog.ivank.net/fortunes-algorithm-and-implementation.html . It's mentioned right at the beginning of [the source file](https://github.com/martijnberger/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/voronoi.c#L28).

Comment: ill be sure to look through it tomorrow
if this is what i need, ill be pretty embarrassed that the solution was right under my nose, but thanks in advance

Comment: ok, that helped a little. Recursion in any actually useful context is still very hard for me to encapsulate from a design perspective. I can see how this method of voronoi helps immensely with performance instead of just looping through each point, but the voronoi.c script remains something to break down another day;

i might take the question down later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to make an implementation of blender's procedural voronoi in unity but this is a little too advanced for me, this answer is just so I can close the question.